# Find next higher element in an array for each element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

From a given input array, for each element, find next higher element present in each array. For example `{40,50,11,32,55,68,75}` output should be `{50,55,32,55,68,75,-1}`. For element if no higher element is present, print -1.

Complexity should be less than `O(n^2)`. You can use data structures and no constraint on space complexity.

Comment: if you sort this array  merge sort O(nlogn) will this not work ?

Comment: @dekdev- You should post that as an answer. :-)

Comment: do you mean http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/ your example doesn't distinguish between next higher and next higher in right side

Comment: @Deepak i think AKS got question wrong. i am deleting my answer

Comment: @dekdev that was good answer for the question he asked

Comment: I don't understand the expected output, why is the fourth element 55 and not 40?

Comment: @Henry Presumably it's the next higher element to the right.

Comment: @Deepak You probably could've posted that as an answer (well, more than just the link, obviously).

Answer (score 38):

You can use a Stack and the time complexity is **`O(N)`**.

**The algorithm:**
Start from the left side and move towards the right. When you pick an element from the array (let's say x), pop the Stack until the elements from the Stack (lets say y) has an element greater than the array element i.e. x> y. Then push the element i.e. x to stack.

e.g.  `{40,50,11,32,55,68,75}` . here `s` is stack.

40, as s is empty push it. `s: 40`

50, as s.peek() < 50 so pop 40 (40's greater element is 50) then push 50. `s: 50`

> Next higher element of 40 - 50.

11, s.peek() > 11 so push 11. `s: 50, 11`

32, s.peek() < 32, so pop the element and now it's 50 which is greater than 32 hence push 32. `s: 50 ,32`

> Next higher element of 11 - 32.

55, s.peek() < 55, so pop the element i.e. 32 then pop next as well as 50 < 55, then push 55. `s: 55`.

> Next higher element of 32 - 55.
>
> Next higher element of 50 - 55.

68, s.peek() < 68 so pop it and push 68. `s: 68`

75, s.peek() < 75 so pop it and push 75 `s:75`.

> Next higher element of 68 - 75.

As the array does not have any element no just pop the stack say that for all the elements inside the array does not have greater element i.e. -1.

> Next higher element of 75 - -1.

**The same algorithm in code:**

```
public static void getNGE(int[] a) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    s.push(a[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (s.peek() != null) {
            while (true) {
                if (s.peek() == null || s.peek() > a[i]) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(s.pop() + ":" + a[i]);
            }
        }
        s.push(a[i]);
    }
    while (s.peek() != null) {
        System.out.println(s.pop() + ":" + -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `while (true)` and `break` rather than just `while (s.peek() != null && s.peek() <= a[i])`?

Comment: You should probably insert the elements into a hash-map and iterate through the input at the end, creating an array with the elements in the correct order (except that it will need to be *a little* more complicated to work for duplicates). Also, I suggest you replace `s.peek() == null` with `s.isEmpty()`, which would make this work with the standard Java API `Stack`.

Comment: @Dukeling `while (true) and break rather than just while (s.peek() != null && s.peek() <= a[i])` ya i accept it. just may be i need to do it soon.

Comment: Nice idea. Version with proper order at http://ideone.com/g14lov

Comment: EmptyStackException is 2 places, corrected one would be          public static void getNGE(int[] a) {
     Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
     s.push(a[0]);
     for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
         if (s.peek() != null) {
             while (true) {
                 if (s.isEmpty() || s.peek() > a[i]) {
                     break;
                 }
                 if(!s.isEmpty()) System.out.println(s.pop() + ":" + a[i]);
}
    }
         s.push(a[i]);
     }
     while (!s.isEmpty() && s.peek() != null) {
         System.out.println(s.pop() + ":" + -1);
     }
 }

Comment: @Trying, your solution looks perfect, but it won't print the elements in order. I thought of using HashMap, but there would be issues for duplicates. Kindly suggest an approach to print the next larger element in the order of the array.

Comment: @BhavukMathur I used a helper class NumClass to store arr element and its index to achieve print the elements in order. Refer to:  https://github.com/yao23/Java_Playground/blob/master/src/FindNextFirstLargerElement.java

Comment: @Trying, To maintain order it's better to push the pair into the stack. ie, The value and the index. In that case, while popping out the value you will get the position to insert the new number and order will be preserved.

Answer (score 3):

A key property of your question, seen in the output 55 for input 32, is that you apparently only want those larger elements which come *after* a given input element in the input sequence. Otherwise the output at that point would have been 40.

I suggest you process the array from the right, and maintain a tree (e.g. a red-black tree) of seen elements. For every element you process, you first seach the tree in O(log n) for the next larger element. You store that in O(1) for the result you want to print at the end, then insert the currently processed element into the tree in O(log n). Processing all elements in this fashion in O(n log n), then reverse the list of things you have to output in O(n) and you are done.

Comment: Up-voting your answer. This is a brilliant approach

Comment: Unless I misinterpret what you are saying, your algorithm is not taking element position into consideration, just the fact that value comes after a given one in the array.This is while, I believe, the original question is about finding the *first* value larger than a given one that comes after a given one in terms of array position.

Comment: To give a concrete example, for the following array:
5 8 7
expected output is as follows:
8 -1 -1
wile your solution will result in:
7 -1 -1
Algorithm presented by @Trying produces the right result.

Answer (score -4):

This is easy:
1. Sort the array. O(n log n)
2. Find each element (index i) in the sorted array and pick element to the right or -1.  Using binary search is O(log n), for each element it is O(n log n)

This could work (in C#):

```
    IEnumerable<int> NextNumber (int[] numbers)
    {
        var sorted = numbers.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
        int cnt = numbers.Count()-1;
        return numbers.Select(sorted.BinarySearch).Select(i => i == cnt ? -1 : sorted[i + 1]);
    }
```

Edit: This solution works if the requested result strictly requires the next higher element regardless of the relative ordering.

Comment: I think the relative ordering of the elements in the original array is significant. Look at the original question and what happens to 32.

Comment: I considered this to be a mistake, but you are right. I will edit my proposal.