# Reference for algorithm to compute next larger elements

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of unsorted numbers, there is a very simple O(n) algorithm to calculate, for each position, the distance (or absolute position) of the next larger element to its right. This algo pops up on many websites (e.g. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/, [Find next higher element in an array for each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720349/find-next-higher-element-in-an-array-for-each-element)), but I was wondering if there is any original reference for it?

Comment: I believe this problem is far too trivial for one to publish an algorithm. This algorithm (like many similar) was probably invented and re-invented zillion of times.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there might've been some very early paper when people could still publish stuff like that ;-)

Comment: It's a reasonable question. There are many, many "little trick" algorithms like this that are too little for academic publication, but where you'd like an authoritative place to look up the needed 5 lines of code rather than having to reinvent the wheel and then convince yourself you actually have a "best practice" answer. Something like what "Numerical Recipes" tried to do for numerical algorithms (though some are critical it).